# Saving excel in clients Machine using Interop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, excel-interop

I'm using Interop Excel to automate excel in my C# code, but at the time of saving it I want that it should give user a popup(just like we get when we download a file from internet with option of open with and save)

I've tried the following but it only saves it on server's HDD

```
xlWorksheet.Save();
xlWorksheet.SaveAs(parameters);
```

anyone can sugget what can be done (**please see: I don't want to use filestream**)

Comment: It's a website or desktop app?

Comment: Its a website, using asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initiate a file download after saving the file in the server

```
public FilePathResult GetFile()
{
    string name = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()+Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".xls";
    // do the work
    xlWorksheet.Save(name);
    return File(name, "Application/x-msexcel");
}
```

*Edited to save the file in the temp folder. Beware that this not guarantees the clean up of the file.*

Comment: It will also save in the server first i guess.
Is there any way that it saves in the temp folder of the server so that it can be deleted automatically on maintenance session

Comment: You can save the file to a memory stream if you don't want to deal with temp files, but you say that you DON'T want to use streams ....

Comment: Edited to save the file in the temp folder

Comment: That was really helpful.
I guess in the servers they periodically clean the temp folder, do they?

Comment: Check out with the IT guys or implement a routine to clean up the files older than 1 day or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you. But i once wrote a WebService that returns my xls as a bytearray and my client App parses it back to a xls

```
public byte[] doSomething() { 
   try {
      var xl = new ExcelWorksheet();
      //...blablabla...
      xl.SaveAs(parameters...);
      if (File.Exists(pathOfXlsDoc)) return File.ReadAllBytes(pathOfXlsDoc);
      return null;
   } finally {
      if (File.Exists) File.Delete(pathOfXlsDoc);
   }
}


----------
```

In clients App it looks like this:

```
private void BuildXls() {
   try {
      File.WriteAllBytes(clientsXlsPath, doSomething());
   } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new Exception("Error!", e);
   }
}
```

Comment: In this also It has to be created on server's HDD first.
if its temp folder of server then there is a possibility that it will get deleted periodically as a part of maintenance schedule

Answer (score 0):

you're probably looking for a save/open file dialog such as this one:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
they open a dialog asking you where to save the file and once you select the location returns that information to your program so you can save the file there.

Comment: Its a Website not a WinForm App